# E: Internal Error, Could not perform immediate configuration (2) on libattr1 ? in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt, aptitude

I am working with Ubuntu latest version. While installing via **apt-get install** i tried to abort that by pressing **Ctrl+Z**. It terminate successfully ;). But next time when i tried to use apt-get, i got some error "lock" and "temporally unavailable" something like that and `**I unfortunately i delete the /var/lib/dkpg folder.**`

after that i cant install anything from apt-get, getting an error.

```
E: Internal Error, Could not perform immediate configuration (2) on libattr1
```

so how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> puts that process in background, so it's still executes, you should do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to kill it.

If you put job in background with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> you can get list of jobs with `jobs` command. And take that job in foreground with `fg %n` where `n` is number of that job as displayed by `jobs`.

You could try deleting `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock`.

Answer (score 0):

Some of methods listed here may work:

http://mm.bbspals.org/linux/lost-var-lib-dpkg-on-debian/